# Windows Server 2016 OpenJDK docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, windows-server-2016, docker-for-windows, docker-java

I'am running docker on windows server 2016, when I try to build an image with a Dockerfile that contains this text:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/eureka-server-one.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8761
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

And run "docker build -f Dockerfile -t eurekaserverone ."
I get the error: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the maifest list entries, I am notgetting this error on a windows 10 manchine. What is causing this error and is there a solution for it?

Answer (score -1):

Why you are providing . at the end of the command

```
"docker build -f Dockerfile -t eurekaserverone ."
```

When you already provided -f flag with dockerfile. Try removing the . at the end and run the build command again.

Comment: The . at the end is so that the command runs in the current directory.

Comment: if that gives same error , then have tried changing to " switch back to linux container " setting by clicking Whale icon in system tray icon?

Comment: There is no whale icon in the system tray on Windows Server 2016